# ZFS pool I/O is currently suspended due to disk mountpoint change (sdb to sdc). How can i fix it?

Tags: mount, zfs, zfsonlinux

the HDD on which was mounted ZFS pool was physically reconnected and the result is that the zfs can no longer find the device at old location /dev/sdb as the drive got new name /dev/sdc.

$ zpool status -v

```
  pool: zfsp
 state: SUSPENDED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to IO failures.
action: Make sure the affected devices are connected, then run 'zpool clear'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-HC
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zfsp        ONLINE       0     0     0
      sdb       ONLINE       3     4     0

errors: List of errors unavailable: pool I/O is currently suspended
```

How can i fix this issue so the zfs use /dev/sdc instead? Or if not good way to go, then how to change disk mountpoint to /dev/sdb back? This is Arch linux. zfs-0.8.5-1, zfs-kmod-0.8.5-1

Any idea please how to mount the pool after reboot from different drive (sdc where before it was using sdb)? Someone suggests: zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/idhere (ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/)

Comment: Can you export the pool? (You’ll have to anyway.)

Comment: no, "sudo zpool export" does not work on suspended pool

Comment: Please provide any error messages in your question. Also try `zpool export -f` and the like.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://github.com/openzfsonosx/zfs/issues/104#issuecomment-30344347) is mentioned hack on how to re-link the device to the mount point ZFS is expecting and prevent reboot.

[here](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/5242) is explained that it may not be currently possible to fix it without rebooting.